# 3 divs on same line but mobile device moves 3rd to new line

Tags: css, flexbox

I have 3 div and would like to keep on same line, I am able to manage for iphone 6 and plus but iphone 5 it again move to next line.
div 1 : dotted line '--------------'
div 2 : text 'Hello world' or other text
div 3 : dotted line '--------------'

```html
<div class="xxx">
  <div style="border-bottom: 2px dotted #ccc;width:37%;display:inline-block;"></div><div style="display:inline-block;"><span>Hello World!!!</span></div><div style="border-bottom: 2px dotted #ccc;width:37%;display:inline-block;"></div>
                    </div>
```

Please suggest how to make it generic or i need to change as per mobile device

Answer (score 1):

You can use flexbox, applying the following settings, which keep the width of the middle element constant (not allowing it to get smaller) and define the other two as 50% wide, but able to shrink as needed:

```css
.xxx {
  display: flex;
  align-items: bottom;
}

.x1,
.x3 {
  border-bottom: 2px dotted #ccc;
  width: 50%;
}

.x2 {
  margin-bottom: -5px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="xxx">
  <div class="x1"></div>
  <div class="x2"><span>Hello World!!!</span></div>
  <div class="x3"></div>
</div>
```